# Change first active toggleClass at page load

Tags: jquery

In a pre-made plugin I would like to change its behaviour with jQuery. It has 3 buttons with a toggleClass (active), button 1,2,3.

When the page is loaded; button 1 is having the class first. How do I manipulate this so that button 2 will have the class at page load, without digging and changing this into the core files?

```
<button id="1" class="w-btn active">I am button 1</button>
<button id="2" class="w-btn ">I am button 2</button>
<button id="3" class="w-btn ">I am button 3</button>
```

What it does; the first button is clicked, so a field appears. Quite basic. I have tried addClass - removeClass, no change, as it is a toggleClass.

Comment: If the value is set by a plugin, does it expose any methods of changing the default selected value? What plugin is it?

Comment: `toggleClass('.active')` would not work; it would have to be `toggleClass('active')`... There's likely an option in the plugin to set which should be active first. Without know what plugin it is, we probably can't help you.

Comment: @heretic-monkey Plugin has no option for this, that would be too easy. The toggleClass needs to start in a different element at page load.

Comment: @rory-mccrossan It's a click toggle, very basic; appearing field, disappearing field.

Comment: @heretic-monkey of course I can share, if this will work for you: WooCommerce Products ShowCase

Answer (score 0):

addClass and removeClass may work...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#1').removeClass("active");
        $('#2').addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Because 'active' is a toggleClass and it will be triggered on click. So adding removing has no function here.

Answer (score 0):

The question has to be taken differently, the `active` class triggers the button to show certain elements. You could try to move the class by using `addClass` and `removeClass`, but high chance this won't work, depending on how harsh the core code is implemented.

The solution to the problem is to make use of the existing toggle behaviour by triggering a click on the button to the one you would like to be triggered. In that case the `active` class will move and the outcome is the same.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#2').trigger('click');
});
```